# Installing SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux on Linux Subsystem for Windows

Tags: linux, windows, sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux on Linux Subsystem for Windows
Does anyone know if this scenario is supported.

There appears to be a library dependency missing in Ubuntu Trusty that this driver requires.

Has anyone successfully got this driver to install and run on lxss?

*** More detail
I followed the installation instructions for the driver here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx

Running ./install.sh verify reports
Starting install for Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

```
> Checking for 64 bit Linux compatible OS
> ..................................... OK Checking required libs are
> installed ........................................ OK unixODBC
> utilities (odbc_config and odbcinst) installed .....................
> OK unixODBC Driver Manager version 2.3.1 installed
> ............................. OK unixODBC Driver Manager configuration
> correct .............................. OK* Microsoft ODBC Driver 13
> for SQL Server already installed ............ INSTALLED
```

Attempting to run bcp causes

> bcp: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.2: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Checking for libodbc.so.2 in /etc/lib - no such directory. It appears to be a part of unixODBC. But sudo apt-get unixODBC gives me "The library is already installed".

I suspect an upgrade to Ubuntu 16.0.4 will fix that, but I don't know if I can do that in lxss.

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/kieran/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]
Description=TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver=libtdsodbc.so
Setup=libtdsS.so
CPTimeout=
CPReuse=

[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: WOPR - How exactly are you configuring the ODBC in your setup? **"This is the first release of Bash on Windows and it is branded "beta" deliberately - it's not yet complete! You should expect many things to work and for some things to fail! We greatly appreciate you using Bash on Windows and helping us identify the issues we need to fix in order to deliver a great experience."** according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide. . . Help explain how you are defining the configurations in your setup please.

Comment: Further detail added

Answer (score 4):

I've found the problem.

I needed to add /etc/lib64 to /etc/ld.so.conf

Then run ldconfig -v to rebuild the library cache

Then I had to upgrade a C++ library by doing
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6

Then **it worked.**